# How can I add values of a column but only where the artist is the same, in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables, first table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[songs]
(
    [ID_Song] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SongTitle] [NVARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    [ListenedCount] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Artist] [INT] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_songs] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID_Song] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[songs] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_songs_artists] 
        FOREIGN KEY([Artist]) REFERENCES [dbo].[artists] ([ID_Artist])
GO
```

And second table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[artists]
(
    [ID_Artist] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_artists] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID_Artist] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

As you can see column `Artist` in table `Songs` references column `ID_Artist` of table `Artists`.

I want to get all `Artists` by summing up `ListenedCount` of all their songs where it's value is greater than a value.

I have trouble writing the query.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you (preferable DML statements to go with those tables). You say you're having trouble with the query; why isn't it working (as you expect)?

Comment: @Larnu I had trouble with writing the query, so that is  the main reason it isn't working xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve it.

One is by summing in a subquery and using it, the sum, as a filter in the query.

```
select art.[Name], gba.[ListenedSum]
from [dbo].[artists] art
join
(
    select sg.[Artist], sum(sg.[ListenedCount]) as [ListenedSum]
    from [dbo].[songs] sg
    group by sg.[Artist]
) as gba on gba.[Artist] = art.[ID_Artist]
where gba.[ListenedSum] > 1000000
```

A more direct way can be using [`HAVING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
select art.[Name], sum(sg.[ListenedCount]) as [ListenedSum]
from [dbo].[artists] art
join [dbo].[songs] sg on sg.[Artist] = art.[ID_Artist]
group by art.[Name]
having sum(sg.[ListenedCount]) > 1000000
```

It's interesting to note the engine can end running these two queries in different ways (not guaranteed) and they can end with different performances.

There's another interesting way, like using a CTE but I think it's a bit more complicated.